# Unable to access window.parent's Xrm.data.entity object from a opened frame web resource Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a html web resource that has

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the head. It is a frame that pops up when a user clicks reject in the ribbon.
When I try to click on a reject button in the frame (not the ribbon), it throws the error "Error: Unable to get property 'entity' of undefined or null reference" I know my

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl()
```

is working because the lookup frame is populated from our server. I have tried the following :

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("approvalstatus").getValue()
```

and

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("approvalstatus").getValue();
```

Both give me errors. I'm totally lost as to why I can't access the parent window's Xrm.Page object. Please advise.

Comment: Try to debug & see if Xrm.Page.data is null, that’s why entity is throwing error while accessing..

Answer (score 1):

Keywords are important.

HTML page within IFRAME in form can access `parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity`

Opening frame (popup as dialog/non-dialog?) from Ribbon button, it depends.

> If you are opening a modal dialog, then you will not be able to access the parent Xrm context - you will need to pass the values in and then when the dialog is closed, update based on the result.
>   If you are opening a non-modal dialog then you can use window.opener

Reference: Scott mentioned in [community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/231484)

Otherwise, send the record Id & Retrieve again in popup window using soap/odata/webapi.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I can see a couple of problems.

#### 1. I don't think you are using `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` correctly

I don't think you should be using`window.parent`.

I think [you should using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328541(v=crm.5).aspx) `GetGlobalContext` which returns `Xrm.Page.context`.

For example; `GetGlobalContext.getServerUrl()`

#### 2. `getServerUrl()` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d7d0b052-abca-4f81-9b86-0b9dc5e62a66%28v=crm.5%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_getServerUrl)

Use `getClientUrl()` instead.

#### 3. I don't believe `GetGlobalContext` gives you access to `Xrm.Page.data.entity` anyway

`GetGlobalContext` only gives `Xrm.Page.context`

`Xrm.Page.data.entity` is a different object.

#### 4. I think you should be [passing form data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328034(v=crm.5).aspx#BKMK_PassFormData) into the web resource

This involves you writing [JavaScript on the CRM form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327945(v=crm.5).aspx), that passes values to the [HTML web resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536(v=crm.5).aspx).

(As opposed to trying to read the CRM form client side from within the web resource. You could also consider making a web service call from your web resource to CRM as well).

> Use the getValue method on the attributes that contain the data that
> you want to pass to the other website, and compose a string of the
> query string arguments the other page will be able to use. Then use a
> Field OnChange Event, IFRAME OnReadyStateComplete Event, or Tab
> TabStateChange Event and **the setSrc method to append your parameters
> to the src property of the IFRAME or web resource.**

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use XrmServiceToolkit. I was trying to update the parent page’s `Xrm.data.entity` from child page that was opened using `showModalDialog` but that doesn’t seem to be possible.

XrmServiceToolkit lets you create SOAP requests that allow you to do all CRM operations. Use the format like explained in this [link](https://worldofitguy.com/2015/02/07/createupdate-entity-using-xrmservicetoolkit-soap/):