# In Dynamics 365, how to customize the email page to add custom image based on email recipient?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

We have an enterprise web api that generates a custom coupon barcode for based on customer id or email.

The Dynamics 365 email activity can send out rich emails; we want to insert custom barcode image into the email.

I have already added a button to this ribbon of this page so that it call open a popup window that can execute my javascript.

But I need to get the email address of the recipient in the "To" field of the email. How do I get this field?

Comment: See if it's helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533086/unable-to-access-window-parents-xrm-data-entity-object-from-a-opened-frame-web

Comment: How are you generating the email? E.g. workflow or SDK?

Comment: @James the emai is a manual activity and the users are using activity--> email to open the form

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening the popup, you can send the contact detail in param. Or you can read the parent form fields like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48533086/7920473) based on your implementation.

Either way, you have to get the [activity party](https://neilparkhurst.com/2015/10/24/javascript-get-activity-party-list/) list from To field & again you have to make a service call to pull email address. Because only Id & Display Name will be readily available in party list or lookup. Everything else has to be retrieved from server.